# Angular component to component

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I have set up a ModalComponent that worked great from a standard UL/LI list. Now however we have implemented the Datatables data grid from the link below. It uses a javascript binding. My service successfully loads the grid, but because I could only get it to load via the data attribute I had to use the internall column binding. This means my markup is static html via their render option.

link: https://datatables.net/

So the the typical (click) event as in the following does not fire:

```
$('#sarDatatable').DataTable( {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']],
        data: this.sars,
        columns: [
            { title: 'SAR Id', data: 'sarSid', type: 'num' },
            { title: 'Intake Date', data: 'formTimeStamp', type: 'date' },
            { title: 'Agency', data: 'agencyName' },
            { title: 'Synopsis', data: 'subjectAdditionalIdentifiers', width: '30%' },
            { title: 'Priority', data: 'sarRecordId', type: 'num' },
            { title: 'Actions', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<button **(click)="modal1.show(sar.sarsId)"** class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon eye"><i class="ti-eye"></i></button>';
              }
            }
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
          search: '_INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
        }
      });
```

So, instead I have to declare a variable with a reference to the data table object and bind a click event based on the style of the element (in this case the "eye" class).

The alert works fine. Problem is now I cannot invoke my ModalComponent's show() method! I've tried using @ViewChild or the option of local variable for component to component interaction but the instance cannot be found. Neither can it find the local method showModal().

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (unvetted.component.ts:64)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (scripts.bundle.js:5226)
    at HTMLTableElement.elemData.handle (scripts.bundle.js:4878)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at HTMLTableElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

My take on this is that even though it is TS the .on(function(... does not have access to the component. How do I achieve this?

My parent componet

```
export class UnvettedComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(SarQuickviewComponent)
  private sarQuickview: SarQuickviewComponent;
  sars: SAR[] = [];
  someValue:String = 'xxxx';

  constructor(private _sarService: SARService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.getSARS();
  }

  getSARS() {
    console.log('getSARS');
    this._sarService.getSARS()
    .subscribe(sars => {
      this.sars = sars;

      console.log(this.sars);
      $('#sarDatatable').DataTable( {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']],
        data: this.sars,
        columns: [
            { title: 'SAR Id', data: 'sarSid', type: 'num' },
            { title: 'Intake Date', data: 'formTimeStamp', type: 'date' },
            { title: 'Agency', data: 'agencyName' },
            { title: 'Synopsis', data: 'subjectAdditionalIdentifiers', width: '30%' },
            { title: 'Priority', data: 'sarRecordId', type: 'num' },
            { title: 'Actions', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<button class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon eye"><i class="ti-eye"></i></button>';
              }
            }
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
          search: '_INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
        }
      });

      var table = $('#sarDatatable').DataTable();
      // Edit record
      table.on( 'click', '.eye', function (this) {
        console.log('click eye');
        console.log(this);
          var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

          var data = table.row($tr).data();
          alert( 'You press on Row: ' + data.sarSid + ' ' + data.agencyName + ' ' + data.title + '\'s row.' );
          this.sarQuickview.show();
      });
    });
  }

  showModal() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

My ModalComponent

```
export class SarQuickviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f') userList: NgForm;
  sar: SAR;
  public visible = false;
  private visibleAnimate = false;
  canAccessUserDropdown: boolean;

  users: User[];
  defaultUser: User;

  constructor(private sarService: SARService,
    private userManagementService: UserManagementService,
    private router: Router,
    private role: RoleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canAccessUserDropdown = this.role.rolesCantAccess(['Reviewer', 'StaffAnalyst']);
    console.log(this.canAccessUserDropdown);

    this.getUserList('CCIC');
  }

  public show(id: number): void {

    // load sar data before making it visible
    console.log('selected id: ' + id);
    this.getSarDetail(id);
    // now show the modal
    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
  }

  public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }

  getSarDetail(id: number): void {
    // invoke service to fetch sar details based on id
    this.sarService.getSARDetailForId(id)
      .subscribe(sar => {
        this.sar = sar;
        console.log(this.sar);
      });
  }

  getUserList(orgName: string) {
    this.userManagementService.getActivatedUsersForOrgName(orgName)
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.users.forEach(user => {
        if (user.userId === +localStorage.getItem('user_id')) {
          this.defaultUser = user;
        } else {
          this.defaultUser = users[0];
        }
      });
    });
  }

  onSubmit(userList) {
    console.log(userList.value.userData.user.userId);
    // this.router.navigate(['/user-management/users/' + userList.value.userData.user.userId]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Try to use arrow function in table.on( 'click', '.eye',  (event) =>

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk Excellent, it works! Curious on what is going on here. By declaring the (event) emitter on table on.click angular knows somehow to bind itself to a javascript event?

Comment: Arrow functions keep context where they were defined, so 'this' is set correctly on invocation

Comment: That makes sense. Can you put in an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Done, buddy. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use arrow function in table.on( 'click', '.eye', (event) =>
Arrow functions keep context where they were defined, so 'this' is set correctly on invocation